# Cannot sort value correctly in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table in this form

```
Name|Quantity|
Item1|600.2|
Item2|8.12|
Item3|78|
Item4|9.723|
```

where all Quantity values are text,

I want to sort all items in descendent order so I have tried this

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT *, CAST(myTableName.Quantity as FLOAT) as Quantity FROM myTableName ORDER BY Quantity desc", null);
```

But the result is this

```
Item4|9.723|
Item2|8.12|
Item3|78|
Item1|600.2|
```

Apparently in the query the dot is ignored in the sorting.

How could I fix this issue getting the right descendant sorting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either change the schema to set `Quantity` to an `REAL` or use a cast *in the `ORDER BY` clause*:

```
SELECT * FROM myTableName ORDER BY CAST(Quantity AS REAL) DESC;
```

(In SQLite `FLOAT` is the [same as `REAL`](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), you can use either.)